# ruby on rails custom query json serialization error: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I do custom query with custom field set in model like this:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :warehouseRecord
  def self.customList()
    Book.
        select("books.id, books.name, warehouseRecord.count").limit(10).
        joins(:warehouseRecord)
  end
end
```

when serialize results to json or when try to output count value to html view

```
@books = Book.customList()

respond_to do |format|
  format.html 
  format.json { render :json => @books }
end
```

I get error: (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1).

If anyone know how to fix it, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should to access to fields localy and use includes(), insted of joins() and write custom select fields: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :warehouseRecord
  def self.customList()
    Book.includes(:warehouseRecord)
  end
end
```

For json representation add customList.json.erb like:

```
<% @books.each_with_index do |book, index| %>
{
  "id" : "<%= book.id %>",
  "name" : "<%= book.name %>",
  "count" : "<%= book.warehouseRecord.count %>"     
}<% unless index == @books.count - 1%>,<% end %>
<% end %>]
```